# Best practice in read data from buffer

Tags: c, buffer, uart

I would like to receive ideas about how to read data from an UART buffer. Being more precisely, I need a way to find some string pattern in the buffer. The problem is that if I wait to search this string, the buffer is written again, the counter changes, and the data can have the pattern or not. Well, I think that this explanation is a little hard to understand, so feel free to ask anything else.

```
void f(char * buffer) {

char * p;
p = strstr(buffer, "abc");

printf(p);
}
```

I think the UART, in my case, is written by blocks and not char by char and there's no way to say that data finished because it's a continuous stream. To better illustrate, it is a code that reads GPS data in NMEA protocol and try to get information from these data.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Could you receive all the data then processing the string? I think the code likes this:

```
char *p_uart = read_from_uart();

void search_string(char *p_uart)
{
    static char last_remain_char[20];
    char new_data[1000] = {0};
    char *p = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    n = snprintf(new_data, sizeof(new_data), "%s%s", last_remain_char, p_uart);
    p = strstr(new_data, "abc");

    strcpy(last_remain_char, new_data + (n - (strlen("abc") - 1)));
}
```

Comment: There's no way to say "all the data"...In my case it's a GPS sending me blocks of data every 1s.

Comment: @Leandro: Could you send the data to another thread, then let this thread to search the string?

Answer (score 0):

You can receive each character and accumulate them (copy) in a regular buffer for comparing later. Or, a better way is to receive each character and keep a state variable to tell you how far you are in the match:

```
size_t state = 0;
while( c=get_char_uart() ) {
    if (str_to_match[state] == c)  {
        state++;
        if (state == strlen(str_to_match)) {
            /* success */
        }
    }
    else 
        state = 0;
}
```

if you are expecting a repeating sequence of characters ("abcabd") it gets trickier. In this case if you fail at `d` you might need to look for `c`. Be warned.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I've seen a lot of people misunderstand how buffers work, so I think I can help.

By what you're saying, you are expecting to read data into a buffer, and are worried that it will partially match your search string.  Then when you read the rest of it, you overwrite the first lot of data.

So, this comes down to how you process your data.  You don't need to read into the same part of memory every time.  The whole point of a buffer is it gives you space that you can fill up, shuffle around if necessary and then discard.

There are many ways to use buffers effectively.  I'll give you the simplest one to understand, although it might not be the most efficient:

When you read into the buffer, you maintain an index (let's call it `tail`) so you know where the last byte is.  You can read up to `N` bytes where `N` is the size of your buffer.  When it comes to processing the data, you can check bytes up to `tail`.

To track what you have already processed, maintain a `head` index.  Once you have determined that you need to read more data, you take everything between `head` and `tail` and move it to the beginning of the buffer (use `memmove`, *NOT* `memcpy`).  You set `head = 0`, and `tail = tail-head`.  Now you can read up to `N - tail` more bytes.  Naturally, you read into a position in the buffer beginning after the `tail` index.

If you want to be able to test the entire match string as consecutive bytes, this is the easiest buffering approach.

If you want to go a step further, it doesn't take much imagination to realise that you don't need to move the data at all.  You can just have `head` chase `tail` around and around.  This is called a *ring* (or *circular*) buffer.  The difficulty with this is you can't use ordinary string matching, but it doesn't take much to roll your own.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: If you want to use `strstr` that's okay.  Make sure you NULL-terminate the buffer each time before you process.  Let's say your match string's length is `X`.  If `strstr` fails to match anything, keep `X-1` characters in the buffer (by moving them to the start and modifying `tail` as I suggested), and read more bytes into the buffer starting at array index `X-1`.  The number of bytes to read are `N-X` - that way you should have one character left to terminate the buffer.

Comment: So let's see if I understood. Every time that I read and process some char I would move all data between what I read and what the tail is pointing to to the begging of the array and then I should set head as 0 and tail as tail minus head. Ok. But, if when I'm moving the data or else when I'm setting the tail pointer, the isr write something else in the buffer? I can't control the write...

Comment: Oh I see.  I didn't realise you were operating directly on the UART buffer.  I would copy the data out of the buffer as fast as possible.  Ideally you would have a thread or interrupt handling routine to do this for you.  Sounds like that's not an option.  Your processing *should* be much faster than the UART, so as long as you are polling it fast or servicing an interrupt you should be okay.  Presumably you can check whether the block has been overwritten.  If not, you could set an unused bit on the first character.

Comment: You said "if you want use strstr that's okay". Any problem with this function that a should know? @paddy

Comment: It's fine to use `strstr` provided you can ensure your string is terminated.  You can't use it if you implement a ring buffer, but it would be okay for the simplified buffering solution I described.  The amount of moving will be small if your search string is small.  I don't really get why you are doing string searching to process NMEA data.  From memory, it gives you whole lines and you need to perform a checksum on the line before pulling out fields.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct, but you must to separate the lines to check the sum and also get parameters.